# Selecting values with regex between two characters

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I need help with regex, I have added some working Playground code on what I am trying to do, to help.

If key="id" it should return: 862
If key="pos" is should return: -301.5, 61.7, 364.6

My RegEx is **var expression = key+"=(.*?)[^,]+"** which is kinda close, but not exactly what I am wanting.

Any help is appreciated!

```
import UIKit

var data = "0. id=862, pos=(-301.5, 61.7, 364.6), rot=(-7.0, -2735.2, 0.0), remote=True, health=125"
var key = "id"

var expression = key+"=(.*?)[^,]+"
var match = data.range(of: expression, options: .regularExpression);
var value = data.substring(with: match!)
print(value)
```

Comment: `id=([^,]+)|pos=\(([^)]+)`

Comment: IDK where you're getting this daata from, but if you have control of it, I recommend you change it into using a standard format (like YAML, JSON, CSV, XML, etc.). It'll be much easier than parsing this

Comment: Close, but still not quite what I am needing. The only value that would change is the "key" variable to select the appropriate value.

Comment: @Alexander I can't control that. Wish I could.

Comment: How about `key+"=(?:\(([^)]+)\)|([^,]+))`

Comment: @Nick that works! Any way to make the result not return the "id=" or "pos=" part?

Comment: @madmunki take a look in the capture groups. Or you could use a lookbehind if swift supports that?

Comment: Try `var expression = "(?<=" +  key+"=)(?:\\([^()]+\\)|[^,\\s]+)"` and then `var value = data.substring(with: match!).trimmingCharacters(in: ["(",")"])`

Comment: That did it Wiktor! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the  strings using

```
var expression = "(?<=" + key+"=)(?:\\([^()]+\\)|[^,\\s]+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/auOpze/1), it matches

- `(?<=pos=)` - a `key` followed with `=` must immediately precede the current position
- `(?:\([^()]+\)|[^,\s]+)` - match either

  - `\([^()]+\)` - a `(`, 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
  - `|` - or
  - `[^,\s]+` - 1+ chars other than whitespace and comma.

Then, after you get the match, remove trailing `(` and `)`:

```
var value = data.substring(with: match!).trimmingCharacters(in: ["(",")"])
```

Comment: Thanks again for this!